# Translating Eiffel loops to languages that do not support loop invariants/variants

Tags: eiffel, loop-invariant

A loop in Eiffel follows this format:

```
from
    Init
invariant
    Invariant
until
    Exit
variant
    Variant
loop
    Body
end
```

How would you translate the above Eiffel pseudo-code to a language that does not support loop invariants/variants?  Let's assume that such target language has an `assert` instruction to check the invariant/variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look like that:

```
Init
last := infinity
loop
    assert (Invariant)
    next := Variant
    assert (0 <= next and next < last)
    last := next
    if Exit then
        break
    end
    Body
end
```

Comment: Excuse me: shouldn't `Variant` be a predicate like `Invariant`?

Comment: @Elena, `Variant` is an expression of an integer type. There is a tag associated with it like with other assertions, but unlike other assertions it is not a Boolean.

Comment: So basically Eiffel checks that `Variant` decreases at each iteration, while staying non-negative, right?

Comment: @Elena, yes, this is the idea to make sure the loop terminates.